# What is the ?_rsc request in NextJS and why are there multiple requests when clicking on a <Link>?

Tags: next.js, react-server-components, next.js14

While writing code utilizing the parallel routes of NextJS,

I realized that

- The backend server's api is being called 6 times.
- All of the API fetch logic for many slots is being called 6 times.
- The middleware is being called 6 times.
- Clicking on the `<Link>` component in the browser generates six http requests with the query parameter `_rsc`.

I didn't find any more top-level reasons why this is happening, so what am I facing and how can I reduce the number of API calls?

Comment: The `_rsc` calls are made the react server component logic, if I am not mistaken it has to do with prefetching.

Answer (score 2):

This was caused by the use of `headers()` in my project and the `cache: 'no-store'` setting in `fetch()`, which resulted in a dynamic page. The segment paths of parallel routes were being refetched after 30 seconds, which I solved with `<Link prefetch={true}>`. Also, the `prefetch` property of the `<Link>` component is `true` for static rendering, but not for dynamic rendering, so you have to apply it manually.